# Problem in installing dlib in PyCharm (macOS)

Tags: python, pycharm, dlib

I am a beginner in the Python programming language. I am Working on a project for facial landmark detection in Python. For this I am trying to use dlib.

I am using PyCharm IDE for Python programming language, but when I am trying to install dlib library on my PyCharm package then I am getting the following error.

[image: error]

Can anyone please help me solving this.

Edit:
Here is the complete error that I am getting.

**Collecting dlib
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/05/57/e8a8caa3c89a27f80bc78da39c423e2553f482a3705adc619176a3a24b36/dlib-19.17.0.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: dlib
  Running setup.py install for dlib: started
    Running setup.py install for dlib: finished with status 'error'
    Complete output from command /Users/mayanktiwari/human_detect/untitled/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='/private/var/folders/ww/21lp_4013plfs5g1ym7wh39h0000gn/T/pycharm-packaging/dlib/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'))" install --record /private/var/folders/ww/21lp_4013plfs5g1ym7wh39h0000gn/T/pip-record-hq673j64/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Users/mayanktiwari/human_detect/untitled/include/site/python3.7/dlib:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    package init file 'dlib/**init**.py' not found (or not a regular file)
    warning: build_py: byte-compiling is disabled, skipping.

```
running build_ext
Building extension for Python 3.7.2 (default, Dec 27 2018, 07:35:52)
Invoking CMake setup: 'cmake /private/var/folders/ww/21lp_4013plfs5g1ym7wh39h0000gn/T/pycharm-packaging/dlib/tools/python -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=/private/var/folders/ww/21lp_4013plfs5g1ym7wh39h0000gn/T/pycharm-packaging/dlib/build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7 -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=/Users/mayanktiwari/human_detect/untitled/bin/python -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release'
-- The C compiler identification is unknown
-- The CXX compiler identification is unknown
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- broken
CMake Error at /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.13.2/share/cmake/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:52 (message):
  The C compiler

    "/usr/bin/cc"

  is not able to compile a simple test program.

  It fails with the following output:

    Change Dir: /private/var/folders/ww/21lp_4013plfs5g1ym7wh39h0000gn/T/pycharm-packaging/dlib/build/temp.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

    Run Build Command:"/usr/bin/make" "cmTC_dc7d9/fast"
    xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun




  CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/private/var/folders/ww/21lp_4013plfs5g1ym7wh39h0000gn/T/pycharm-packaging/dlib/build/temp.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/private/var/folders/ww/21lp_4013plfs5g1ym7wh39h0000gn/T/pycharm-packaging/dlib/build/temp.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/private/var/folders/ww/21lp_4013plfs5g1ym7wh39h0000gn/T/pycharm-packaging/dlib/setup.py", line 261, in <module>
    'Topic :: Software Development',
  File "/Users/mayanktiwari/human_detect/untitled/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools-40.8.0-py3.7.egg/setuptools/__init__.py", line 145, in setup
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/distutils/dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/Users/mayanktiwari/human_detect/untitled/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools-40.8.0-py3.7.egg/setuptools/command/install.py", line 61, in run
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/distutils/command/install.py", line 545, in run
    self.run_command('build')
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/distutils/command/build.py", line 135, in run
    self.run_command(cmd_name)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/private/var/folders/ww/21lp_4013plfs5g1ym7wh39h0000gn/T/pycharm-packaging/dlib/setup.py", line 135, in run
    self.build_extension(ext)
  File "/private/var/folders/ww/21lp_4013plfs5g1ym7wh39h0000gn/T/pycharm-packaging/dlib/setup.py", line 172, in build_extension
    subprocess.check_call(cmake_setup, cwd=build_folder)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 347, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['cmake', '/private/var/folders/ww/21lp_4013plfs5g1ym7wh39h0000gn/T/pycharm-packaging/dlib/tools/python', '-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=/private/var/folders/ww/21lp_4013plfs5g1ym7wh39h0000gn/T/pycharm-packaging/dlib/build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.7', '-DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=/Users/mayanktiwari/human_detect/untitled/bin/python', '-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release']' returned non-zero exit status 1.

----------------------------------------
```

Command "/Users/mayanktiwari/human_detect/untitled/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='/private/var/folders/ww/21lp_4013plfs5g1ym7wh39h0000gn/T/pycharm-packaging/dlib/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'))" install --record /private/var/folders/ww/21lp_4013plfs5g1ym7wh39h0000gn/T/pip-record-hq673j64/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Users/mayanktiwari/human_detect/untitled/include/site/python3.7/dlib" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/ww/21lp_4013plfs5g1ym7wh39h0000gn/T/pycharm-packaging/dlib/**

Comment: Are you using a virtual enviroment or the default python interpreter?

Comment: Can't open the "error", please paste it here.

Comment: Have you followed the advice in the error message? If so, what were the results? Also, please copy the _full exact error message_ and include it in your post.

Comment: @GamingWithAltitude, I am using default python interpreter.

Comment: @Aaron_ab, I have posted the complete error message.

Answer (score 2):

`conda install cmake`

Then

`pip install dlib`

It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer to this question. We just need to follow simple steps to install dlib in Python.

1. Install Python
2. Install Pycharm
3. Install Anaconda

Open anaconda, create a new enviornment, and then execute the following commands in the same order.

- conda update conda
- conda update anaconda
- conda install cmake
- conda install -c conda-forge dlib

Now in this way you can install dlib on anaconda's virtual enviornment. Next you can access this virtual enviornment inside your Pycharm editor.